# Can you change the image hosting for a TWTweetComposeViewController from Twitter to something custom?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I would like to tweet from my app with an image, but I want to host the image on my server and have the tweet point to that.

I would like to not have to reimplement the entire UI of TWTweetComposeViewController (I know I can do this by just coding against NSUrl and TWRequest).

Looking at the API, it looks impossible, but perhaps there are 3rd party GUI codebases written on top of TWRequest or a way to reuse the Sheet GUI, but get the final button click and handle it myself (with TWRequest calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not, but if you'd like to, you might want to look into [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit).

Comment: ShareKit looks awesome, but unfortunately their two implementations either (1) don't use TWRequest at all, so have limited integration with iOS Twitter support or (2) use TWTweetComposeViewController.  I might be able to start from (1), reuse their GUI (adding multi-account support) and use TWRequest instead.  Thanks.

Comment: DETweetComposeViewController is definitely a good starting point for a GUI -- thanks.